# Enhancing Paint quality

Tags: java, swing, graphics2d

I have this paint project that I did using JPanel and Graphics2D. Everything is good except that the quality of the paint itself is bad and is pixelated. How can I improve it? This is where I setup my brush:

```
public void setupbrush (){    
    strk= new BasicStroke(4, Stroker.CAP_ROUND, BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND);
    bru1=(Graphics2D)jPanel1.getGraphics();
    bru1.fillRect(0, 0, getSize().width, getSize().height);
    bru1.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
                bru1.fillRect(10, 10, getSize().width, getSize().height);
                bru1.setPaint(Color.red);
                bru1.setStroke(strk);


                }
```

[image: This is the outcome]

Answer (score 3):

I have this nice little library method I use a lot...

```
public static void applyQualityRenderingHints(Graphics2D g2d) {
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION_QUALITY);
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_COLOR_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_COLOR_RENDER_QUALITY);
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_DITHERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_DITHER_ENABLE);
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_FRACTIONALMETRICS, RenderingHints.VALUE_FRACTIONALMETRICS_ON);
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL, RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_PURE);
}
```

I highly recommend that you have a play around with the values and see what works for you.

The first thing you should never do, is apply this to copy of `Graphics` you didn't create first.  This is important, as `Graphics` is shared resource which is used by all the components in your window, so making changes to it could have unexpected results

This means this...

```
bru1=(Graphics2D)jPanel1.getGraphics();
```

will be a problem, but not just for this answer.  `getGraphics` is not how painting works, apart from been able to return `null`, anything you paint to it can be wiped clean the next time a paint cycle occurs

Take a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details about how painting should be done.

Then, once you've correct for that, then your `paintComponent` method might look something like this...

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
    applyQualityRenderingHints(g2d);
    // Do your custom painting here
    g2d.dispose();
}
```